Getting "BigQuery adapter: 404 Not found: Dataset `PROJECT_ID:`DATASET_ID` was not found in location EU. How to change dataset location in dbt Cloud?
I would like dbt Cloud to not look for the BigQuery dataset/table I ask it to query in location US but instead in location EU. How and where do I configure this in dbt Cloud? I see no opportunity to do this anywhere in the settings. I have defined a sources.yml file with name, schema and table fields but have no profiles.yml file since I am using dbt Cloud. Thank you in advance!

It is probably not the location but the name of the table(or dataset ID) and  better explained in this Answer
Also the documentation included in the answer suggests

To specify a custom schema for a model, use the schema configuration key. As with any configuration, you can do one of the following:

{{ config(schema='marketing') }}

select ...


Could you please have a look at the link you shared? It seems like it is not working. Thanks!
